# Failing to send verification while signing up in the messaging app

Tags: javascript, html, email, reactjs, sendbird

I made a web-app which uses sendbird as messanger component, to be able to use the app everyone needs to register first. But for some reason the registeration part not working no more after several days of testing. The code hasn't changed since just the user delete and created again.

Anyone knows where the problem might comes from, is it not because of spaming the email? What should I do if it is.

**When I want to login the messaage is :
No user registered with this e-mail
-- When I want to register is :
You have already signed up. Please check your email to verify your account
 OR 
Vertifaction failed to send.**
index_bundle.js:5348 Error creating SendBird User: {"original":null,"response":{"req":{"method":"POST","url":"https://api.sendbird.com/v3/users","data":{"user_id":"sth@sth.com","nickname":"Testttttttt","profile_url":""},"headers":{"content-type":"application/json","api-token":"ff8bf5060352c01ce575287f25def5be4b02fd6d"}},"xhr":{},"text":"{\"message\":\"user_id violates unique constraint.\",\"code\":400202,\"error\":true}","statusText":"BAD REQUEST","statusCode":400,"status":400,"statusType":4,"info":false,"ok":false,"redirect":false,"clientError":true,"serverError":false,"error":{"status":400,"method":"POST","url":"https://api.sendbird.com/v3/users"},"accepted":false,"noContent":false,"badRequest":true,"unauthorized":false,"notAcceptable":false,"forbidden":false,"notFound":false,"headers":{"content-language":"en","content-type":"application/json"},"header":{"content-language":"en","content-type":"application/json"},"type":"application/json","links":{},"body":{"message":"user_id violates unique constraint.","code":400202,"error":true}},"status":400}

Comment: `user_id violates unique constraint.`

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but really negative vote wasn't neccesary!! Not everone are pro, should consider newbie people too. @DanielA.White

Comment: Yes I can see violate unique constraint, but I deleted all the user inside sendbird dashbord and now the dashbord is having empty array. How am I violating that?

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

[SendBird Dashboard - Users] Check [All] in the status filter at the top to see if you have deleted all the Deactivate users.